Using ImageView matrix or directly cropping from a Bitmap, how do I use something like center-crop, but from a specific point/rectangle?
Background
I have some images that I need to put into ImageView that has specific size.
The problem
I can use center-crop, but often the images that are shown will cut important parts of the images.
I want to be able to tell the ImageView to try its best to show a certain region (point/rectangle) while cropping the rest and yet not stretching but just fitting to both width&height of its size.
So, let's say the ImageView is a square one (aspect ratio 1:1), and the image to crop from is a rectangle, it means I would be able to crop not just from the center or from the sides, but also somewhere in between:

What I've found
There seem to be plenty of Github repositories and snippets that offer a solution similar to this issue :

https://github.com/cesards/SuperImageView
https://github.com/omgnuts/JCropImageView
https://github.com/yqritc/Android-ScalableImageView
https://gist.github.com/sromku/73254681b933406b701b
https://github.com/NicolasDuponchel/ScalableImageView
https://gist.github.com/arriolac/3843346

However, each of them only supports cropping to the edges/corners.
What I want to do is to tell it exactly where in the Bitmap is the important part to try to keep, and then fit from there and crop out the rest.
I don't mind to either extend ImageView and using its Matrix to have this, or getting a new Bitmap out of the original one (including via Glide, for example). Could also be nice to know of both types of solutions.
A possible way to understand it and make a bad solution of it, is to have a loop that starts from the important point, and increases its size in width&height to match the aspect-ratio of the ImageView and on each iteration it will increase the width by some number and the height by some number, till it reaches the edges. This is correct only theoretically, because practically it will lose some pixels on the way due to rounding of calculations, and it's also inefficient as it uses a loop where it could use a direct calculation instead.
The question
Is it even making sense ? Is it possible to implement such a thing?
If so, can you please show code of how to do it?
